# Execute a subprocess that takes an input file and write the output to a file

Tags: python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I am using a third-party `C++` program to generate intermediate results for the python program that I am working on. The terminal command that I use looks like follows, and it works fine.

```
./ukb/src/ukb_wsd --ppr_w2w -K ukb/scripts/wn30g.bin -D ukb/scripts/wn30_dict.txt ../data/glass_ukb_input2.txt > ../data/glass_ukb_output2w2.txt
```

If I break it down into smaller pieces:

- `./ukb/src/ukb_wsd` - executable program
- `--ppr_w2w` - one of the options/switches
- `-K ukb/scripts/wn30g.bin` - parameter K indicates that the next item is a file (network file)
- `-D ukb/scripts/wn30_dict.txt` - parameter D indicate that the next item is a file (dictionary file)
- `../data/glass_ukb_input2.txt` - input file
- `>` - shell command to write the output to a file
- `../data/glass_ukb_output2w2.txt` - output file

The above works fine for one instance. I am trying to do this for around 70000 items (input files). So found a way by using the `subprocess` module in Python. The body of the python function that I created looks like this.

```
with open('../data/glass_ukb_input2.txt', 'r') as input, open('../data/glass_ukb_output2w2w_subproc.txt', 'w') as output:
        subprocess.run(['./ukb/src/ukb_wsd', '--ppr_w2w', '-K', 'ukb/scripts/wn30g.bin', '-D', 'ukb/scripts/wn30_dict.txt'],
                       stdin=input, 
                       stdout=output)
```

**This error is no longer there**

*When I execute the function, it gives an error as follows:*

```
...
STDOUT = subprocess.STDOUT
AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'STDOUT'
```

*Can anyone shed some light about solving this problem.*

**EDIT**

The error was due to a file named `subprocess.py` in the source dir which masked Python's subprocess file. Once it was removed no error.

But the program could not identify the input file given in `stdin`. I am thinking it has to do with having 3 input files. Is there a way to provide more than one input file?

**EDIT 2**
This problem is now solved with the current approach:

```
subprocess.run('./ukb/src/ukb_wsd --ppr_w2w -K ukb/scripts/wn30g.bin -D ukb/scripts/wn30_dict.txt ../data/glass_ukb_input2.txt > ../data/glass_ukb_output2w2w_subproc.txt',shell=True)
```

Comment: Why don't you run the subprocess in Python exactly the same way you run in the shell in your Terminal?

Comment: That is my current solution. I put the entire command within quotes and add `shell=True` and it works. But it seems that when working with files, using `stdin`, `stdout` is the preferred way. Maybe I am wrong in this case.

Comment: Some people, IMHO probably those who work nearer the Web and untrusted users, are concerned about security and sanitising input and shell injection attacks and they prefer `stdin`. Other folks, maybe those who collaborate with other people towards shared goals in closed environments of scientists and engineers, are maybe more relaxed about things. Everyone's mileage may vary.